# Relative Layout Android Studio Textview collapsing together

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

[How I want it to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR1z3.png)

[How it is showing after rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqtMS.png)

I am using Relative layout within a scroll view and the problem occurs with the alignment of the 4 `TextView`'s, when the left and right `TextView`'s fall on each other in the center.

Here is the code for the relative view.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="415dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/Sindh_"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sindh_cases"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/Punjab"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Punjab_cases"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The first and second text views are the ones on the left and the third and fourth are the ones on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin between the bottom `TextViews` to make sure they are separated

After modification:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="415dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/Sindh_"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sindh_cases"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/Punjab"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Punjab_cases"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Using ConstraintLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="415dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sindh"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/Sindh_"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sindh_cases"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_sindh" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_punjab"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="@string/Punjab"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_sindh" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Punjab_cases"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Sindh_cases"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_punjab" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also note that you are exaggerating in margin values, for instance using a `415dp` margin at the top can be too much for some devices, and it's already too much for the landscape orientation; where the bottom Views won't show on the screen unless wrapping it in `ScrollView`

Comment: And this can be done more better using `ConstraintLayout` by setting constraints between both TextViews to avoid intersection between them. Let me know if you need it

Comment: It would be great to get a setting in constraints layout. Because no other solution has worked yet.